# How does one web file be used by many subdomains?

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, subdomain, cpanel

I have many subdomains that use one web file and the same url structure, example: sub1.domain.com, sub2.domain.com, sub3.domain.com, and etc.
All subdomains will use web files contained in sub1.domain.com with the same url structure, example: sub1.domain.com/page1 then sub2.domain.com/page1.
Is that possible with cpanel using htaccess? Thanks.

Comment: I think for this you should make virtual host files and point all the virtual host to the same directory and then point all the domains or sub-domains to the IP of that server with help of `A` records. This will work.

Comment: If you have a separate http server simply use a fallback http host in your setup which serves all host names likewise, or configure separate hosts to use the same `DOCUMENT_ROOT`.